# How to correct Sublime Text 4 opening any file half-line scrolled

Tags: sublimetext4

My Sublime Text 4 is opening files with their top lines going scrolled beyond the tab bar and half shown (attaching the screenshot). You'll see that the top line of the css file (which is html element) is half scrolled. This is happening to all the files regardless of their type.

[image]

I tried setting `caret_extra_top` and `caret_extra_bottom` to zero but didn't help. Also set `line_padding_top` and `line_padding_bottom` to zero but this too didn't help.

Can you please help in solving this for me? Just in case, I'm using Menlo at 10 size as the font in sublime.

Comment: Never used sublime (preferred, VS Code and Atom), but try uninstalling and installing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, finally. Answering it here for anyone who stumbles upon this in future after being creative with his/her IDE like myself. Lol

I had used a python script which collapses/folds content of the file by given level upon opening the file. It was this functionality which was causing this behaviour. No matter the levels to fold the content, it is scrolling the first line by half. Just disabling/ removing that